# Does 1 Tim 5:17 indicate a real distinction between ruling vs teaching elders?

Tags: greek, grammar, 1-timothy

> 1 Tim 5:17 (ESV) Let the elders who rule well be considered worthy of double honor,
>   especially those who labor in preaching and teaching.
>
> 1 Tim 3:2 (ESV) Therefore an overseer must be above reproach, the
>   husband of one wife, sober-minded, self-controlled, respectable,
>   hospitable, **able to teach**... (emphasis added)

Based on 1 Tim 5:17, is there support for a distinction between elders that only rule and elders that rule *and* preach/teach?

[PCUSA](https://www.opc.org/qa.html?question_id=309) believes it is and I see some commentators support it ([JFB](http://www.studylight.org/commentaries/jfb/1-timothy-5.html#1); [Robertson](http://archive.org/stream/expositorsgreekt04nico#page/133/mode/1up) a la Expositor's Greek Testament; [Enduring Word](https://enduringword.com/commentary/1-timothy-5)), but I also see the requirement of teaching in 1 Tim 3:2 along with the other qualifications which would indicate no distinction in offices. [Matthew Henry](http://www.studylight.org/commentaries/mhm/1-timothy-5.html#1) is also in this latter camp.

Comment: Good question. Many Presbyterian denominations make this distinction (PCA, EPC, OPC). It would be interesting to trace the history of it. But I don't think the answer can be found in 1 Tim 5 alone as the theology of that distinction takes into account passages that show the office of pastor to be distinct.

Answer (score 2):

The term in 1 Timothy 3:2 is ἐπίσκοπος (*episkopos*), whereas the term used in 1 Timothy 5:17 is πρεσβύτερος (*presbyteros*). The two offices continue to exist to the present day within the Greek Church the same names, with *episkopos* translated into English as "bishop" and *presbyteros* as "presbyter" or "priest".

I not sure one can infer anything conclusive about the roles and responsibilities at the time from a single verse.  We do know that by the end of the 1st century there was a clearly defined clerical hierarchy consisting of *episkopoi*, *presbyteroi*, and a third office, *diakonoi* (deacons).  All three are mentioned in the *Praxapostolos* of the New Testament, but there is not as clear a distinction in the roles of *episkopoi* and *presbyteroi* as emerged later.  Ignatius of Antioch (35-108) wrote, for example,

> Be ye subject to the bishop as to the Lord, for he watches for your
> souls, as one that shall give account to God [viz. Hebrews 13:17].
> Wherefore also, ye appear to me to live not after the manner of men,
> but according to Jesus Christ, who died for us, in order that, by
> believing in His death, ye may by baptism be made partakers of His
> resurrection. It is therefore necessary, whatsoever things ye do, to
> do nothing without the bishop. And be ye subject also to the
> presbytery, as to the apostles of Jesus Christ, who is our hope, in
> whom, if we live, we shall be found in Him. It behoves you also, in
> every way, to please the deacons, who are [ministers] of the mysteries
> of Christ Jesus; for they are not ministers of meat and drink, but
> servants of the Church of God. They are bound, therefore, to avoid all
> grounds of accusation [against them], as they would a burning fire.
> Let them, then, prove themselves to be such.
>
> [*Epistle to the Trallians*, Chapter II](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/anf01.v.iv.ii.html)

The [*Apostolic Canons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canons_of_the_Apostles) ([I](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf214.xvii.iv.html) and [II](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf214.xvii.iv.html)) indicated that *episkopoi* were to be ordained by other *episkopoi* and that *presbyteroi* and *diakonoi* were to be ordained only by an *episkopos*.

A Russian Orthodox presbyter and theologian, Michael Pomazanski, provides a good overview, I think, of what the New Testament Scriptures tell us about the *presbyteroi*:

> Presbyters (literally “elders”) were both in Apostolic times and in
> all subsequent times — and are today [in the Eastern Orthodox Church]
> — the second degree of the hierarchy. The Apostles Paul and Barnabas,
> as the book of Acts relates, going through Lystra, Antioch, and
> Iconium, ordained presbyters in each Church (Acts 14: 23). For the
> resolution of the question about circumcision, an embassy was sent to
> Jerusalem, to the Apostles and the presbyters at Jerusalem (Acts 15:
> 2). At the Council of the Apostles, the presbyters occupied a place
> together with the Apostles (Acts 15: 6).
>
> Further, the Apostle James instructs: *Is any sick among you? Let him
> call for the elders* (presbyters) *of the Church, and let them pray over
> him, anointing him with oil in the name of the Lord* (James 5: 14).
> From the instruction of the Apostle James we see that (1) presbyters
> perform the Church’s sacred rites, and (2) in the early Church there
> could be several presbyters in each community, whereas only one bishop
> was appointed for a city and the region around it.
>
> In the twenty-first chapter of the book of Acts, it is related that
> when the Apostle Paul returned to Jerusalem after his third Apostolic
> journey and visited the Apostle James, all the presbyters came,
> signifying that they made up a special Church rank. They repeated in
> the hearing of Paul the decree of the Apostolic Council concerning the
> noncircumcision of the pagans; but they asked him to perform the rite
> of his own purification, so as to avoid the reproach that he had
> renounced the name of Jew.
>
> [*Orthodox Dogmatic Theology* (3rd ed.)](http://amzn.to/2m1Yuhv), pp.253-254

Regarding the ambiguity between *presbyteros* and *episkopos*, he further writes:

> In the Apostolic writings the two names of “bishop” and “presbyter”
> are not always distinguished. Thus, according to the book of Acts the
> Apostle Paul called to himself in Miletus the “presbyters of the
> Church” from Ephesus (Acts 20: 17), and instructing them he said, *Take
> heed therefore unto yourselves, and to all the flock, over which the
> Holy Spirit hath made you bishops* (overseers)*, to feed the Church of
> God, which He hath purchased with His own blood* (Acts 20: 28).
> However, from these and similar expressions one cannot conclude that
> in the age of the Apostles the two ranks — bishop and presbyter — were
> joined into one. This shows only that in the first century church
> terminology was not yet as standardized as it became later, and the
> word “bishop” was used in two meanings: sometimes in the special
> meaning of the highest hierarchical degree, and sometimes in the usual
> and general meaning of “overseer,” in accordance with the Greek usage
> of that time.
>
> *Ibid*., p.254